# jquery resize div

Tags: jquery

I am writing a little function to resize my search div to stay the same width as the dynamic table below. Why does it work if I don't use a function, and then fails if i do use the function. I would like to use a function for this as I have multiple gridview/searchs.

Javascript Code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                   function ResizeSearch(GridID, SearchID) {                              
                          alert("\"" + GridID + "\"" + ' ' + "\"" + SearchID + "\"");
                          var eleWidth = $("\"" + GridID + "\"").width();
                           $("\"" + SearchID + "\"").width(eleWidth);
                       };
                       $("#getp").click(function() {
                       ResizeSearch("$(#<%= gvValidStatus.ClientID %>)", "$(#ValidStatusSearch)");
                       /* 
                       ****** Why does this work, but when passing to function it does not? ******
                       var eleWidth = $("#<%= gvValidStatus.ClientID %>").width();
                       $("#ValidStatusSearch").width(eleWidth);
                       */
                       });
                   });
```

Output from Alert

```
---------------------------
Windows Internet Explorer
---------------------------
"$(#ctl00_Content_gvValidStatus)" "$(#ValidStatusSearch)"
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: For one you are creating a jQuery object and then turning it into a jQuery object again. You don't need to wrap `GridID` and `SearchID` in `$()`'s.

Comment: It's very strange that `$("$(#ValidStatusSearch)")` provides something useful. I suppose the main effect of using the function is doing nothing instead of doing something.

Comment: Jasper, you should have answered as obviously this is the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function ResizeSearch(GridID, SearchID) {                              
    var eleWidth = $("#"+GridID).width();
    $("#"+SearchID).width(eleWidth);
}
$("#getp").click(function() {
    ResizeSearch("<%= gvValidStatus.ClientID %>", "ValidStatusSearch");
});
```